# How to turn off scroll lock LED, indicating keyboard layout, when the PC is turned off

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shutdown

I edited the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-keyboard-layout.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard-all"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    #Option "XkbVariant" ""
    Option "XKbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
    Option "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

When the layout is "US", scroll lock diode is turned on. When the layout is "RU", it's turned off.

Everything works correctly, **but when I turn off the PC, scroll lock stays turned on. Is it possible to turn it off, when the PC is shut-down?**

Comment: That's odd, most PCs power off the keyboard when they're shut down. What type of keyboard do you have? How are you shutting down the computer?

Comment: @Gilles The keyboard is an old 101 Packard Bell keyboard, made in 1995. I shut down the computer by clicking: "Start" -> "Log out" -> "Shut down" in XFCE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`setleds`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds) command to change the keyboard leds.

```
setleds -num -caps -scroll
```

You'll need to run this from a script executed during shutdown. How to do this depends on what init system your system uses.

With a traditional SysVinit or a system that supports emulation of its scripts, if you have directories called `/etc/init/init.d` or `/etc/init.d`, create a script called `local_turn_off_leds` in this directory containing

```
#!/bin/sh
setleds -num -caps -scroll
```

Make it executable (`chmod +x local_turn_off_leds`) and register it to be executed during shutdown for poweroff:

```
ln -s ../init.d/local_turn_off_leds /etc/rc0.d
```

If your init system is Upstart, which is the case if you have a directory called `/etc/init`, you can [create an Upstart job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78298/how-do-i-configure-upstart-to-run-a-script-on-shutdown-when-the-process-takes-lo) instead.

For Systemd, see [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)

Comment: No, it doesn't work