# Unable to run git commands before shutdown

Tags: systemd, fish

I would like to use `systemd` to accomplish this if possible. This is what I have done so far.

1. Wrote a script in `fish` that will stage, commit and push files to a repository. Script made executable with `chmod u+x <script>.fish`.
2. Wrote a service unit.
3. Reloaded with `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, enabled with `systemctl --user enable backup.service`.

This is the fish script.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

set note_dir /home/yjh/Documents/notes

cd $note_dir

set today (date "+(%A) %B-%d-%G %T")

git add . 
git commit -am $today
git push origin master
```

This is the service unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup obsidian notes before shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Before=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=fish /home/yjh/scripts/backup.fish

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

This is the service unit file after I applied the link to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294047/how-to-write-a-systemd-unit-that-will-fire-before-networking-goes-down) provided by Freddy. That answer linked to [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown) and I also applied those changes but it still didn't work.

I have ran the script in two ways manually with `./<script>fish` and through starting it with systemctl like this `systemctl --user start backup.service` and they both are able to push my code to github. I have already setup SSH for that specific repository, so, no password or username is asked when I want to push to github.

Comment: Related: [How to write a Systemd unit that will fire before networking goes down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294047)

Comment: I did not consider the network to be shut down. Thanks @Freddy. I'll look into the link.

Comment: @Freddy I took a look at the linked answer and I added my comment in a quote block. Basically it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR, try this simplified version:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup obsidian notes before shutdown
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=fish /home/yjh/scripts/backup.fish

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Running this as a user service, my test script was not automatically started (**inactive (dead)** instead of **active (exited)**). At first I used `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in the install section. But this target is not available running user services, same as the `halt.target` or `reboot.target`. Switching it to `WantedBy=default.target` made the difference, see [Systemd service does not start (WantedBy=multi-user.target)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666509).

Removing `DefaultDependencies=no` adds implicit dependencies `Conflicts=shutdown.target` and `Before=shutdown.target`, see [systemd.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#Default%20Dependencies) and [systemd.special#shutdown.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#shutdown.target).

Reenable the service after editing it to change the symlinks:

```
systemctl --user reenable backup.service
```

Then reboot and shutdown again to see if it works.

Comment: This helped, the only thing that was missing is an extra `shutdown.target` in `WantedBy=`. Could you update your answer before I accept it?

Comment: AFAIK the install section is only responsible to enable the service and to start it and should be one the boot targets. I removed `DefaultDependencies=no` to add implicit dependencies to the shutdown.target, see my edit. You can view the dependencies with `systemd-analyze --user dump`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks so much.