# Delay system shutdown with systemd?

Tags: systemd

What is the best way to delay system shutdown by arbitrary amount of time in `systemd`?

I'm trying the following unit:

```
root@ip-172-30-3-65:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/delay_by30.service
[Unit]
Description=Delay Shutdown by 30 sec.
#Before=apache2 nginx php5-fpm

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However I'm getting very mixed up results. For the starters my `ExecStop` line somehow is executed on `systemctl start` and my `ExecStart` on `systemctl stop`, other way around than it should be. Time stamps in the `journalctl` confirm this:

```
root@ip-172-30-3-65:~# systemctl enable delay_by30.service 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/delay_by30.service to /etc/systemd/system/delay_by30.service.
root@ip-172-30-3-65:~# systemctl start delay_by30.service 
root@ip-172-30-3-65:~# systemctl stop delay_by30.service 
root@ip-172-30-3-65:~# journalctl -n 4 -u delay_by30
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-01-06 17:05:34 GMT, end at Mon 2017-01-09 15:57:34 GMT. --
Jan 09 15:55:59 ip-172-30-3-65 systemd[1]: Starting Delay Shutdown by 30 sec....
Jan 09 15:56:29 ip-172-30-3-65 systemd[1]: Started Delay Shutdown by 30 sec..
Jan 09 15:57:34 ip-172-30-3-65 systemd[1]: Stopped Delay Shutdown by 30 sec..
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: When `systemd` is instructed to should down the system, it should sleep at least 30 secs before doing so.

Comment: @NarūnasK That's what you're trying to do, but what are you trying to _accomplish_ by doing that? There's probably something _even better_ which can solve your actual root problem.

Comment: @don_crissti Totally irrelevant, but if you must know: host shuts down quicker than AWS LB can notice it, hence delayed shutdown solves this problem, otherwise LB send traffic to host, which does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `RemainAfterExit=yes` to your `[Service]` section. Right now systemd is seeing your process (`/bin/echo`) exit, at which point it considers the service to have exited, and proceeds to stop it.

(You can probably also just not have an `ExecStart` line, but I didn't test that.)

Comment: indeed the ExecStart isn't needed, as [explained here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41756)...

Comment: Without `ExecStart` it would be ideal, however I'm getting `delay_by30.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.`

Comment: @NarūnasK I'd guess it depends on the systemd version.