# How do I change the time limit on systemd shutdown scripts?

Tags: centos, systemd

I have a script that I want to run just before shutdown on my CentOS 7 machine. [A process to do so using systemd is well-described in this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown?rq=1). Basically, I just drop the script I want to execute into `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` and it will run automatically.

This works, but my script can take a while (several minutes). It seems that there is a 90-second timeout, after which my script gets killed and the system proceeds to halt. How can I change this time limit?

Based on the [discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4hjgo8/shutdownreboot_delay_for_90_seconds/), I tried setting `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=infinity` and `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=infinity` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, but it didn't have the desired effect.

**Edit:**
I dug a little more and found the reason why: when shutdown scripts are run this way, they are executed by the `systemd-shutdown` binary. Its source code can [be found here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/shutdown.c). Specifically, this piece of code is responsible for executing the scripts:

```
execute_directories(dirs, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_USEC, NULL, NULL, arguments);
```

`DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_USEC` is defined in `basic/def.h` as follows:

```
#define DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_USEC (90*USEC_PER_SEC)
```

So there appears to be a hard-coded 90-second limit, making this mechanism useless for my need here. What other method would be appropriate to run a script at shutdown? Could I create my own systemd service that is `WantedBy` the halt target? I would like to run the script once the filesystems have been remounted readonly (so pretty late in the process).

Comment: Running `systemctl show SERVICE_NAME.service -p TimeoutStopUSec` you could see the timeout set by systemd to service.

Instead of editing the package's service file in /usr/lib/systemd/system/ which will get overridden on package upgrade, use:
`sudo EDITOR=/bin/vi systemctl edit <service-name>`
This will safely edit the file /etc/systemd/system/service-name.service.d/override.conf.

This file need only contain:
`[Service]`
`TimeoutStopSec=5000  # or whatever value you want`