# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: systemd, mysql, shutdown, reboot, socket

All commands in debian9's interactive non-login shell (graphical mode).
I want to backup mysql before reboot or shutdown.

```
who 
test tty7         2018-02-01 18:26 (:0)
test@world:~$ pwd
/home/test
```

Now the following three commands can backup mysql database.

```
USERNAME="xxxx"
PASSWORD="yyyy"
mysqldump -u root -p${PASSWORD} database > /home/test/wp.sql.bak
```

Create a service running before reboot or shutdown.

```
vim  /etc/systemd/system/test.service  

[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/test/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The test.sh file .

```
cat  /home/test/test.sh
USERNAME="xxxx"
PASSWORD="yyyy"
mysqldump -u root -p${PASSWORD} database > /home/test/wp.sql.bak
```

Enable the service.

```
sudo systemctl enable test.service
sudo reboot
```

Now log into interactive non-login shell (graphical mode).

```
sudo systemctl enable test.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-02-01 18:26:04 HKT, end at Thu 2018-02-01 18:27:23 HKT. --
Feb 01 18:26:13 world systemd[1]: Starting Run command at shutdown...
Feb 01 18:26:18 world bash[480]: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")"
Feb 01 18:26:19 world systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Feb 01 18:26:19 world systemd[1]: Failed to start Run command at shutdown.
Feb 01 18:26:19 world systemd[1]: test.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 01 18:26:19 world systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

The three commands can run in terminal instead of containing in test.service,how to write a service backuping all mysql datadb when reboot or shutdown?

Comment: Looks like your mysql instance has been stopped before the backup runs.

Comment: Use the ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/test/test.sh in the actual mysql service template. This should execute the backup before mysql is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/test/test.sh` rather than `ExecStart`.  See [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown) for more information.  You appear to be running your script on startup, presumably before mysql is fully started.

Second, consider adding `After=mariadb.service` to be sure the script is run before mysql is shut down.  Remember that, when considering shutdown order, everything is in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target  
After=mariadb.service 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/test/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It is mariadb in debian9 instead of mysql.