# How to add a delay to the power button for accidental bumps

Tags: centos, power-management, shutdown, acpi

I have a miniature PC here with a large and prominent power button on the front which is easy to bump accidentally.

The system is running CentOS 7 with systemd.

I already know that I can set `HandlePowerKey=ignore` in `/etc/systems/login.conf` but this disables it entirely.

What is the procedure for addressing this on CentOS?

Comment: Try using a e.g. `sleep 5` script [before shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226/22142)

Comment: Headless or DE? (I have a gnome solution that shows a dialog box...)

Comment: This is a CentOS minimal install so there is no desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Some while ago I created this handy script: https://github.com/stackcoder/doublepress

It can prevent accidental shutdowns by requiring double pressing the power button. It's written for Debian, but I'm pretty sure it can be also installed on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to tackle this via BIOS level setting.

There should be a setting in power or system management with reference to power button.  It normally has two options: instant action, and delayed for a couple of seconds.

Comment: I would agree but there is no such option on this BIOS.