# Is there a logout equivalent of ~/.profile?

Tags: command, logout

The file `~/.profile` can be used to specify commands to run when a user logs in to a session. This has the advantage over `~/.bash_profile` in that it works for shells other than bash and also works for at least some desktop environments (e.g. it works for me logging into Mate). However, I am wondering if there is an equivalent to `~/.profile` for logging out, which (unlike `~/.bash_logout`) will run commands on user logout for other shells as well as the Mate DE?

(note: I tried the obvious `~/.logout` and it didn't seem to work)

**To clarify, in response to some of the comments:**

I am using **OpenRC, not systemd**, so the answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226/257802) doesn't help me. This is not in any way a duplicate of that question. I am looking for something that would be independent of the init system and also *per user*, not system-wide (hence the comparison to `~/.profile`).

I think 'no' would be a perfectly acceptable answer, if the answer is 'no' (with perhaps an explanation of what is the 'proper' way to run commands on logout from the DE for a user).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)

Comment: What I do in my `$HOME/.profile`: `test -f "$HOME"/.exitrc && trap '. "$HOME/.exitrc"' EXIT`

Comment: @GillesQuenot I am actually using OpenRC, rather than systemd, so unfortunately the answer to that question doesn't help me.

Comment: @Mikel thanks for your suggestion - I will give it a try. So, that suggests the answer to my question may be 'no'?

Comment: @Mikel I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The trap doesn't seem to fire, either on user logout or full system reboot.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/3087/cmdline` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot it says 'No such file'. Why would there necessarily be a process 3087? Which process are you trying to query?

Comment: Sorry: `cat /proc/$$/cmdline`

Comment: @GillesQuenot it says 'bash'. bash is my default shell.

Comment: So, you can use `~/.bash_logout`

Comment: @GillesQuenot no, it doesn't work. I've tried it. `~/.bash_profile` also doesn't seem to work for logging *in* to the DE (even though bash is my default shell); however, `~/.profile` does.