# Backup with rsync when the system shutsdown

Tags: systemd, rsync

I created a script that backs up the selected folder to a remote server using rsync. Everything works fine when I manually run the script. But I would like it to be done automatically when the system shuts down. And this is where I get an error:

```
 13:19:12 mx rsync_update.sh[9512]: Host key verification failed.
 13:19:12 mx rsync_update.sh[9506]: rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
 13:19:12 mx rsync_update.sh[9506]: rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
```

The unit looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Clean on reboot,shutdown
Requires=network.targe rsync.service 
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/rsync_backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Rsync works via ssh.

Comment: who is the owner of the script when you run it manually vs. when you run it via `systemd`?

Comment: The owner of the script is root

Comment: Check possible duplicate questions/answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226/14907 https://askubuntu.com/a/1163373/89385 https://askubuntu.com/a/1024394/89385

Comment: Welcome, there's a typo in `Requires=network.targe`, it's missing the final 't'.

Comment: It seems like it's trying to use an `ssh` key to contact the server, but it's unable to find a (correct) key.   I wonder if the `ssh-agent` has already shut down.  If not, try explicitly choosing the identity file with `-i /root/.ssh/id_rsa` (or equivalent).

Comment: Requires=network.target corrected. But there is a mistake.

Comment: I also think the problem is with the ssh that quit. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please verify that `root` can log in to the remote location.

Comment: Please show me how to do it? Although I have already said, the manual script works well

Comment: "_Requires=network.target corrected_" - no it's not. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/763555/edit) to fix it. We can only answer what you give us.

Answer (score 0):

When a *shutdown* is initiated (init 0, init 6) that service kicks off a bunch of other services that then kills existing services.  If you don't explicitly specify in your custom systemd script to kick off your `rsync` copy before other things are killed, then your service can happen at any point in time during the shutdown process which is bad.  Does it happen before or after the `ssh` service is killed?  Does it happen before or after the file system is unmounted?  Before of after the network is killed? And so on.

You want to make sure your rsync backup is, preferably, the very first service that happens after you type *reboot* or *shutdown*, and that other services/targets are running such as `sshd` and `network-online.target`  I believe the answers here in this link below, I think it mostly has your solution but not necessarily in only one answer response.  Given your requirements there will be some amount of extra consideration needed in your choices of what you specify for `Wanted By` and `Requires`.  I get a chance I will post a template type of systemd service you're asking.

[How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown/479048#479048)