Execute a script when powering off, but not when rebooting (using systemd)
I'm working on scripts to power the TV connected to my Mac (running Linux) on and off. These scripts make use of the cec-ctl util (part of video4l), which control the CEC pin of the HDMI output.
The main goal is to switch the TV off on shutdown (but not when rebooting).
So, how can I setup a systemd service/unit to execute a script as the last thing before powering off, but not when rebooting?

This question is similar to: How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Refer to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39250/260833

@ArtemS.Tashkinov, the question is clearly different as it specifies the script must be run when powering off and not when rebooting.  The answers provided in the referred question you point to (which I have seen before asking here) doesn't differentiate the scenarios (and the proposed solutions there don't work as they execute the script in both scenarios).  Thank you

The automatically-posted boilerplate text is sometimes oversimplified and misleading, by which I mean wrong.  We consider a question to be a duplicate if the other thread contains the answer to this one. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  Look at Piotr Jurkiewicz’s answer: “add [a] script executable to the /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown directory.”  The script will be run with one argument: “either "poweroff", "halt", "reboot" or "kexec", depending on the chosen action.”  So you should try writing a script that looks at its argument and switches the TV off if the argument is "poweroff" (or "halt"?), but not "reboot".

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', although Piotr's answer doesn't really anser my original question, which is how to perform this using service/unit, his proposed solution using the/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/ directory is a simpler to address the specified problem.  Thank you.  OBS: After some research on how to do this, I did found a way of doing this using a service (I'll answer my own question), but a simpler solution will be better.

I tried to start a script, when powering off and it worked.
Made a service unit called myservice.service
[Unit]
Description=Run mycommand at shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=poweroff.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -->absolute path to script<--

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target

placed it in /usr/lib/systemd/system and enable it
systemctl enable myservice.service

did you test this to be sure it does not run the script when doing a reboot?

@ron yes i tested it, no action on reboot. Does it not work on your system?

few notes on the service and the script:

after placing your something.service file under the desired systemd folder location, do a systemctl daemon-reload for it to be recognized when doing a systemctl list-unit-files along with enabling it.
another location is /etc/systemd/system/
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/using_systemd_unit_files_to_customize_and_optimize_your_system/assembly_working-with-systemd-unit-files_working-with-systemd-
if selinux is enabled, then you have to set an appropriate selinux label on your script specified by ExecStart otherwise that script will not run

I have not come up with a better label than bin_t to use; I believe it is mostly subjective
bin_t seems to be what is used on all the other services if you check them via ls -ldZ
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/path_to_your_script/script.sh"
restorecon -vf /pathtoyourscript/script.sh
and of course if you find yourself yelling why isn't this working, before you punch the screen try... setenforce 0




This doesn't really answer the question.  Although useful, it should be added on comments instead.

i would have if the comments allowed that much detail

After some deep research on how to execute a script using a service/unit but only when the system is being powered off, I managed to find a conditional execution that determines if this is a power down using the systemctl list-jobs command:
Determining within a script if the system is going to poweroff:
jobs=$(systemctl list-jobs)

if echo "$jobs" | grep -q "poweroff.target.*start"; then
  echo "System is going to poweroff"
  exit 0
fi

Anyway, as pointed out by @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica ' in a comment, Piotr Jurkiewicz’s answer to a similar question proposes a simpler soluction that does address the specified objective. (Thank you @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica for raising this to my attention.  Really appreciated)
OBS: The only actual advantage this approach offers over Piotr's approach is that it allows the script to be run before filesystems get mounted readonly.  But to achieve the goal I had when asking, it didn't make any difference anyway.
